# how to show all items of a RecyclerView in a view that contains a NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I would like to display all the elements of my list on the screen but I am not able to. Basically this list contains 5 elements and can contain more and more. For this, the screen needs a scroll, so I put a NestedScrollView on the screen so that as there are more elements in the list, the user can go down and view all the elements in the list. But there's a problem, I can't display the whole list, it only shows the first element and inside the RecyclerView and the Scroll is inside the list and the screen is weird and I can't show it all.

See the XML:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_passos">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_solido_branco"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_passos">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_seu_resumo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/oxygen"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_374F78"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_consultar_itinerario"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_seu_resumo"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_consultar_itinerario" />
```

With this code my screen looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXOL0.jpg

But I need it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBn8e.jpg  (in this case I put a fixed size in the height of the RecylerView)

Because I don't know how many elements there will be in the list, it will vary according to each user. But for some strange reason the screen doesn't go down anymore, it seems that NestedScrollView bugged something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right what you want to achieve is a screen with an text at the top and then below that you want to have a list of items. In case this is right, you don't want that your whole screen is scrollable but only your items in your list. Making both scrollable creates this weird behaviour which should be avoided in my opinion.

So in order to achieve what you want is changing your layout with the one below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_passos">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_seu_resumo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/oxygen"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_374F78"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listafrutta"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_seu_resumo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: I would like to show all the elements of the list and make the screen scrollable with NestedScroll, because I will have no idea how many elements this list will have, it will depend on each user, so the screen has to be in agreement

Comment: Generally you can't display all elements of the list at once in a screen. This is due the fact that all screens have different sizes and it depends on the number of items and their layout. What you do is create a Recyclerview. This view will display as many items as fit in the screen and while you scroll down it will replace the view that was first with the new coming one. You should read about https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/getting-to-know-recyclerview-ea14f8514e6.  Did you try out the XML that I've posted to see how it looks?